# Significant query time difference on Cloud SQL & Local server

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I'm executing the following query on a Cloud SQL instance (type D1 mysql 5.6.16) where it takes 11 seconds to complete. On the exact same database with the same indexes and content running on mysql (v5.5.35)  on my shared hosting (which is nothing special in terms of specs) the query takes just 0.068 seconds.

Query:

```
SELECT casenotes.caseworkerID,COUNT(*)
FROM emails LEFT JOIN (casenotes) ON  (emails.ID=casenotes.subtypeID) 
WHERE emails.type='sent' AND casenotes.type='email' AND 
      emails.datetime > '2014-05-01' 
GROUP BY casenotes.caseworkerID;
```

This is the explain result on Cloud SQL server

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  casenotes   ref type,subtypeID,caseworkerID type    22  const   6447    Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  emails  eq_ref  PRIMARY,ID,type,datetime    PRIMARY 8   casework_test.casenotes.subtypeID   1   Using where
```

This is the explain result on my shared hosting

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE  casenotes   ref type,subtypeID  type    22  const   6451    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  emails  eq_ref  PRIMARY,type,datetime   PRIMARY 8   zahawizs_caseworker.casenotes.subtypeID 1   Using where
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can tweak either my select statement or the Cloud SQL server instance to return this faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who is having trouble with this, I have found that the tables in question were in MyISAM, chaining to INnodb has significantly sped up searches. Apparently the cloud SQL cache is better suited for InnoDB tables.

This isn't a 100% solution though as on a large data set the query is still taking nearly 3 seconds to complete on cloud SQL so any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, please don't use MyISAM. InnoDB provides transactional support and does it's own memory managment. Cloud SQL is optimized for InnoDB. Also, the queries that use filesort are currently slow in Cloud SQL. So, for best performance, please avoid that.

Comment: Any suggestion as to how to avoid file sort with that query or force a different method

Comment: Does removing the GROUP BY makes the filesort go away?

Comment: It does, adding order by Null seems to have sorted it.